# Saving binary data in a browser without it getting UTF8 encoded on download

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64

My web app receives data in the form of a base64 encoded string, which is decodes using atob, and stores via URL.createObjectURL().  This data is then downloaded via the right-click save-as dialog.  The downloaded filed always matches the source file when the source file is ascii encoded.  However this isn't the case when the source file is just plain binary data.  A diff of a non ascii encoded downloaded file vs its source file appears to show that the downloaded file is UTF-8 encoded.  How can this problem be fixed?  Please note, I'm locked into using firefox 10.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, UTF-8 is supposed to have backward-compatibility with ASCII.

But, if you'd like, you can try to send out a header. For example, a UTF-8 HTML page would have the header "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8".

Comment: @ShengSlogar UTF-8 is backward-compatible with ASCII, but ASCII is only 7 bits. If you have an 8-bit stream you can get into trouble.

Comment: @some So how would you force ASCII encoding? What charset would that be? "charset=ascii"? How about UTF-16 or 32?

Comment: @ShengSlogar Base64 is a way to force a binary stream into ASCII :) It is common to set the content-type to `application/octet-stream` when you want to keep it binary.

Comment: @some So that means @BrianMiller should force it with ``application/octet-stream``?

Comment: @ShengSlogar I think that is the solution for a binary file. If it should be treated as a text-file one should set it to the correct charset.

Comment: @some Which is what Brian Miller wants; so that would be the correct answer?

Comment: Im fairly certain I'm using supplying 'application/octet-stream' in the call to getBlob() prior to calling URI.createObjectURI() (i don't have access to the code right now.

Comment: @ShengSlogar No, the correct answer would be how to get it to work in Firefox 10.

Comment: @some But headers are headers, it dosen't matter what browser, right? (I think I'm getting confused here... :))

Comment: @ShengSlogar There is a difference in how browsers handle headers. `URL.createObjectURL()` is a new technology still in experimental stage.

Comment: @some Okay, so we're going to need a "genius" to answer this. :)

Comment: @ShengSlogar Or read the documentation, write a test case, test it, tweak it, test some more, and then publish a working example. :)

Comment: @some And bring myself down using Firefox 10? :)

Comment: @ShengSlogar If it is there the problem is, yes: It's not that hard. Just download a virtual machine, and install FF10 on it. You usually learn something when trying to solve a problem. When trying to solve someone else's problem you don't have to solve it, and only spend time on it while you think it is fun.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a Arraybuffer and it should work. If there is any way that you can get the data into an array buffer directly without passing a sting that would be the best solution.

The following code is tested in FF10, and are using the now obsolete MozBlobBuilder.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/some/maY38/)

```
var str="",
    idx, len,
    buf, view, blobbuild, blob, url,
    elem;

// create a test string
for (var idx = 0; idx < 256; ++idx) {
  str += String.fromCharCode(idx);
}

// create a buffer
buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
view = new Uint8Array(buf);

// convert string to buffer
for (idx = 0, len = str.length; idx < len; ++idx) {
  view[idx] = str.charCodeAt(idx);
}

blobbuild = new MozBlobBuilder();
blobbuild.append(buf);
blob = blobbuild.getBlob('application/octet-stream');
url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

elem = document.createElement('a');
elem.href = url;
elem.textContent = 'Test';
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Comment: Thats for the reply but the above code doesn't seem to work with firefox10.  By that I mean I tried it (via blob builder) and when I download it to a file the contents just read ArrayBuffer...

Comment: @BrianMiller Ok, I'm downloading FF10 and will install it in a virtual machine so that I can test it for you. Please stand by.

Comment: @BrianMiller Ok, `Blob` wasn't available until FF13, so using MozBlobBuilder instead. In append it should be the `ArrayBuffer` and not the `Uint8Array` view that should be added. I removed the endian test since it looks like it don't need it.

Comment: Ok. Same results... a look at the follow char

Comment: Ok. Same results... but I've identified the issue, this char  ÿ, which is equivalent to chr(255) in the source file becomes this in the downloaded file Ã¿, chr(255).  I also found this article http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html  .. So im confused as to how to fix this issue

Comment: @BrianMiller Please add the base64 encoded string to your question (or at least a base64 encoded string that gives the problem). The code in my answer above is tested in FF10, with every character from 0 - 255 and it works.